# Any shorthand JavaScript to make this reducer easier?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to "skinny down" and list of objects to many less attributes, but still a lot.  My code looks like this:

```
function reduceSpeakersData(speakers: Speaker[]) {
    return speakers.map(function(speaker: Speaker) {
        //return speaker;
        return ({
            id: speaker.id,
            firstName: speaker.firstName,
            lastName: speaker.lastName,
            imageUrl: speaker.imageUrl,
            company: speaker.company
        })
    });
}
```

I know if I have:

```
firstName: firstName
```

I can make it just

```
firstName
```

But not sure what I can do with

```
firstName: speaker.firstName
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What's the structure of Speaker?

Comment: For sure you can make it shorter. But shorter isn't better.

Comment: if you need to return shallow copy of all the properties of `speaker` you can do just `return {...speaker};`. if there are some property you want to exclude there is no short way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to shallow clone, then ...

```
   speakers.map(speaker => ({ ...speaker }))
```

if you need to exclude some properties, you can destructure:

```
   speakers.map(({ to, exclude, ...speaker }) => speaker)
```

if you however need to exclude as many values as you have to include, then there is no short way. You could use a helper, e.g.:

```
    const pick = (head, ....tail) => obj => !head ? {} : Object.assign(pick(...tail), { [head]: obj[head] });

   speakers.map( pick("id", "firstName", /*...*/) )
```

Answer (score 1):

may be something like that with adding some destructing object concept

```
const reduceSpeakersData = (speakers: Speaker[]) => {
      return speakers.map(({ id, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, company }: Speaker) => ({
        id,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        imageUrl,
        company
      }));
    };
```

Comment: Interesting, still mentioning the variable twice though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use destructuring in the parameter list, and an arrow function:

```
function reduceSpeakersData(speakers: Speaker[]) {
    return speakers.map(({id, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, company}: Speaker) =>
        ({id, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, company})
    );
}
```

Comment: fun fact: Thats longer than the OPs version.

Comment: @JonasWilms The lines might be longer, but it's a lot fewer lines? Not sure we're talking about the same "OPs version"?

Comment: Right, the next time someone asks for shorter code I will do "replace \n with ", than you only have one line ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Even the total amount of characters is a lot less. Why are you calling this "longer"? It avoids the repetition of `speaker.`.

Comment: If you replace `speaker` with `s`, then we talk about two characters per replacement. Thats not "a lot less".